# Big O Complexity for Solving NP-hard Problem

Tags: optimization, time-complexity, big-o, gurobi, np

I have an NP-hard optimization problem that I formalized as mixed-integer linear program (MILP) and that I'm solving (for small inputs) with [Gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/).

I understand that NP-hard means that there's no polynomial time algorithm for solving the problem, unless P=NP.
Is there any more precise bound I can give on the time complexity for solving the problem (e.g., with Gurobi) using the Big O notation?
Any way of approximating the impact of the different input sizes on the complexity?

Comment: Is there a way to simulate it? If so, then run several thousands simulations, scale in every possible dimension and monitor the time and the resource consumption. It might help you to get a feeling for the result.

Comment: Yes, there is and I have done an empirical evaluation of the algorithm's runtime, but I'd like to have a theoretical complexity bound too.

Besides, the empirical evaluation is heavily limited by the enormous runtime. It would take forever to run thousands of trials.

Comment: Seems more like a question for the Computer Science site. If I recall correctly, this kind of approximation can be done by matching your problem with an already existing and well known problem. Alternatively you can try to reason out the necessary steps and complexity yourself (e.g. how many operations are there in each step, how large is the branching factor, what does it depend on etc.) It will require quite a deep dive into the problem at hand and possibly also looking at how the solver works with your representation.

Comment: So it depends on the specific solver? I was hoping that there may be a general bound for solving MILPs based on their number of variables, constraints or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The field of mixed-integer programming is way too diverse to define a complexity rule depending on the number of variables or constraints. You need to check the literature concerning your specific problem or application - for many concrete problems, there are complexity results available. And this still does not necessarily carry over to the performance of a particular solver or whether you can actually solve a specific problem instance.